# If I break my tayammum of ghusl by breaking a wind am I in a state of Janabah or not?

Tags: fiqh, ghusl, tayammum

I have made tayammum for Janabah, I can manage to make wudhu, but not ghusl.

My question is, if I make tayammum for janabah then go to toilet or break a wind, does it put me in a state of Hadath Akbar or hadath Asghar?

Comment: I assume you have a valid reason for not being able to perform ghusl which apparently applies for those body parts which are not part of the wudu', am I correct?

Comment: Yes, due to circumstances I cannot perform ghusl. But I can perform wudhu

Comment: This is a complicated matter that requires a fatwa by a knowledgeable scholar. Also, it will differ by school of jurisprudence and even within the same school depending on whether tayammum is viewed as a backbone (Arabic: عزيمة) or a license (Arabic: رخصة), and as an absolute alternative (Arabic: بدل مطلق) rather than an out-of-necessity alternative (Arabic: بدل ضروري). It is not a simple question that can be addressed without proper context and knowledge of your situation and the conditions allowing you to perform wudu' and not ghusl; definitely not a topic for anonymous users to answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Islam SE is not a fatwa site. While questions about the legality of actions from a fiqh-generic perspective are acceptable, answers by anonymous users do not identify poster's level of knowledge, education or expertise. You should consider consulting a _mufti_ in your area. Questions of this nature will most likely be closed. Please refer to [ask], and take a [tour] in our [help].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Islam SE is not a fatwa site. While questions about the legality of actions from a fiqh-generic perspective are acceptable, answers by anonymous users do not identify poster's level of knowledge, education or expertise. You should consider consulting a well-versed scholar in your area.